# How can I switch between angular components without reloading the entire webpage?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I'm trying to create three components that can be switched between with a navbar at the top. When I click on the navbar to switch to a different component, I want the navbar to stay static at the top and not reload, only the new component should load.

I've tried some tutorials for navigation bars like this one: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black

I've also tried using a '?' in the path of the 3 components, for example, path: 'toplevel?component1'

Everything I try still reloads the entire page. Is there a way to keep the navigation bar static like this between two components?

Comment: Absolutely yes. This is very straightforward to achieve with @angular/router. You need to provide your code including your routing configuration and how your component structure currently looks.

Comment: Please share a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look at what you have tried so far. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: You can look at angular official routing example here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/byydyxrjoag

Comment: you seem to be lost. Read [angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router), check [angular's tower of heroes example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/stackblitz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to solve this:

**1. A right way (using a routing):** https://angular.io/guide/router

**2. A simple way:**

TS:

```
class SimpleComponent {
    value: number;
}
```

HTML

```
<component-0 *ngIf="value === 0"></component-0>
<component-1 *ngIf="value === 1"></component-1>
<component-2 *ngIf="value === 2"></component-2>
```

You can use ngSwitch too.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways,

1. it's best practice to use routing, and to keep the navbar static all you have to do is this:

   ```
   <nav>This is your navbar</nav>    
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ```

Where components are actually routes.

2. Another way is using [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) like this:

   ```
   <ng-container [ngSwitch]="component">
   <app-component-1 *ngSwitchCase="1"></app-component-1>
   <app-component-2 *ngSwitchCase="2"></app-component-1>
   <app-component-3 *ngSwitchCase="3"></app-component-1>
   </ng-container>
   ```

   with navbar interaction changes the value of "component"

Hope it helps